# Python sorted list [a1, a2 ... b1, b2]

Tags: python, python-3.x

This a list that i sorted:

```
>> list1.sorted()
>> list1
    ['tmp-0.gif', 'tmp-1.gif', 'tmp-10.gif', 'tmp-11.gif', 'tmp-12.gif', 'tmp-13.gif', 'tmp-14.gif', 'tmp-15.gif', 'tmp-16.gif', 'tmp-17.gif', 'tmp-18.gif', 'tmp-19.gif', 'tmp-2.gif', 'tmp-20.gif', 'tmp-21.gif', 'tmp-22.gif', 'tmp-23.gif', 'tmp-24.gif', 'tmp-25.gif', 'tmp-26.gif', 'tmp-27.gif', 'tmp-28.gif', 'tmp-29.gif', 'tmp-3.gif', 'tmp-30.gif', 'tmp-31.gif', 'tmp-4.gif', 'tmp-5.gif', 'tmp-6.gif', 'tmp-7.gif', 'tmp-8.gif', 'tmp-9.gif']
```

I need this:

```
['tmp-0.gif', 'tmp-1.gif', 'tmp-2.gif' ... 'tmp-31.gif']
```

not:

```
['tmp-0.gif', 'tmp-1.gif', 'tmp-10.gif'...]
```

---

[Does Python have a built in function for string natural sort?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4836710/does-python-have-a-built-in-function-for-string-natural-sort) solve the problem, but i will need to download methods... and the answer below solved the problem using only basic python

Comment: there is more than one answer that does not require you to download anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One method to do this -

```
list1.sort(key= lambda x: int(x.split('.')[0].split('-')[1]))
```

Example -

```
>>> lst1 = ['tmp-0.gif', 'tmp-1.gif', 'tmp-10.gif', 'tmp-11.gif', 'tmp-12.gif', 'tmp-13.gif', 'tmp-14.gif', 'tmp-15.gif', 'tmp-16.gif', 'tmp-17.gif', 'tmp-18.gif', 'tmp-19.gif', 'tmp-2.gif', 'tmp-20.gif', 'tmp-21.gif', 'tmp-22.gif', 'tmp-23.gif', 'tmp-24.gif', 'tmp-25.gif', 'tmp-26.gif', 'tmp-27.gif', 'tmp-28.gif', 'tmp-29.gif', 'tmp-3.gif', 'tmp-30.gif', 'tmp-31.gif', 'tmp-4.gif', 'tmp-5.gif', 'tmp-6.gif', 'tmp-7.gif', 'tmp-8.gif', 'tmp-9.gif']
>>> lst1.sort(key= lambda x: int(x.split('.')[0].split('-')[1]))
>>> lst1
['tmp-0.gif', 'tmp-1.gif', 'tmp-2.gif', 'tmp-3.gif', 'tmp-4.gif', 'tmp-5.gif', 'tmp-6.gif', 'tmp-7.gif', 'tmp-8.gif', 'tmp-9.gif', 'tmp-10.gif', 'tmp-11.gif', 'tmp-12.gif', 'tmp-13.gif', 'tmp-14.gif', 'tmp-15.gif', 'tmp-16.gif', 'tmp-17.gif', 'tmp-18.gif', 'tmp-19.gif', 'tmp-20.gif', 'tmp-21.gif', 'tmp-22.gif', 'tmp-23.gif', 'tmp-24.gif', 'tmp-25.gif', 'tmp-26.gif', 'tmp-27.gif', 'tmp-28.gif', 'tmp-29.gif', 'tmp-30.gif', 'tmp-31.gif']
```

Comment: you're the best, thank you